# Intermittent write locks on files without obivous cause

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, file-management

**Recently I have been getting intermittent (random, sporadic) write locks on recently written files without any obvious cause.**

**The setup:**

The machine in question is a 2 years old DELL Latitude E6520 with Samsung SSD PM830 250 GB disk on Windows 7 Professional SP 1 and Sophos 10.3 antivirus.

It is my work computer used as a main machine for software development, so there is a lot going on most of the time with the disk. I also use the Hibernate function of the Windows 7 once a day (to start the next day just where I had left).

**What goes wrong:**

The machine had performed just right from the start up until the second to last week. lately, when I compile a program*, I get a 'Permission denied' from the compiler when linking the main file and subsequently 'File is locked by another process' error when trying to delete the old exe file manually. The file remains locked for some time (order of minutes) and then just disappears on its own. The same thing happened when I downloaded a file from the Web with Chrome - the temporary zero-length file couldn't get deleted upon completion of the download and I got stuck with an empty .zip (or whatever) file and .zip.part with the complete data. Later I successfully deleted the empty file and renamed the .part file and all went along pretty well, there was no damage to the file. The problem, however, so far never occurred when saving one of the source files or any other plaintext or Office files - and it takes saving a few source files to get one .exe file that causes the problem.

*This is what I do most often, so I find it natural to get the error in this situation quite often, too.

**Done so far:**

I restarted the development IDE (Qt Creator) and the whole computer, didn't help.

I tried the process explorer (linked from one of Microsoft's KB pages) to determine who is locking the file in question, only to find System.exe and nothing else.

**Suspects:**

My first suspects would be a hardware failure of the SSD Disk (worn out cells) or the antivirus. I can't disable the antivirus (and don't know how to check whether there is the antivirus really behind the system.exe lock) and am not familiar with tools specifically aimed at checking SSD disks (I do not want to get one of *those* testing tools, I'm sure you understand). But these are just my thoughts. I would like to try out some more possibilities before submitting my laptop to our IT department...

---

Edit: I'm currently trying to find out whether the disk is in proper working order. I will post the results here as soon as I have any.

Comment: You need to verify the SSD is in working order.  So you will need to use one of those testing tools provided by the OEM of the drive most of the time, before we can help you.  If you cannot do it because of IT policy then you need to go to your IT department.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm on it, hopefully will be back soon enough with results.

Comment: Wait. Are you *sure* it's `system.exe`? With the `.exe`? Because that's not a normal file. The kernel is represented in Task Manager as `System`. A `system.exe` is not from Microsoft. If you really do have such an entry, there's a good chance you have malware on that machine.

Comment: The SSD was ruled out. I had a new one installed with a 1:1 binary copy from the old one and the problem remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the problem is not happening on text files, etc, but on zips, exe's, etc, my money would be on the antivirus causing it.. it's checking the file for safety, and when it's done it unlocks it.
If you have the option, try telling the AV to only check files on open, its probably checking on open and close. If they're not checked on close, there is the possibility of downloading an infected file... however as long as you're checking on open, you still have a degree of protection

Comment: Unfortunately I can't verify that it is the antivirus in my case (my PC has already _taken care of_ by our IT dept.) But since a new HDD didn't help, I'm guessing that the antivirus is the next best bet. Thank you for your answer!